Times time and a half Daniel 7:25
After reading the description of the 4 beasts and the detsiled description of the beast with iron teeth that is different, who blasphemes God, persecutes the saints and seeks to change laws and the times; couldn't the times, times and a half refer to the original and legal presidential term of 4 years as a time, times as 8 and a half as 2, giving us 14 years before that power is destroyed by Christs return? Why does it have to be a value understood in ancient times but a current value of this time pertaining to current leadership values of democratic countries that will change?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
